# AngularJS - How to get directive-controller in directive with "require"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a directive with a require. Now I want to get the required controller instance AND the controller of the directive in the link function. How is that possible? If i set 'require' the fourth parameter of the link function only contains the required controller. If I do not set the requirement the fourth parameter of the link function contains the controller of the directive. How to get both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should require both, then the 4th argument will be an array of controllers (in the same order as the required directives.

E.g. from the source code of Angular's `ngModel` directive (which needs access to both `NgModelController` and its wrapping form's `FormController`):

```
var ngModelDirective = function() {
    return {
        require: ['ngModel', '^?form'],
        controller: NgModelController,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrls) {
            ...
            var modelCtrl = ctrls[0],
                formCtrl  = ctrls[1] || nullFormCtrl;
            ...
```